# Pass XML data to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using this library to convert JSON to XML: https://github.com/abdolence/x2js

I am trying to pass the converted XML to my MVC controller as follows:

```js
let model = new Model();
model.ArticleName = "Test";

$.each(AttachmentsArray, function(i, item) {
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(item.DocumentData));
  model.Files.push(
    new File(item.FileName, item.FileData)
  );
});

var x2js = new X2JS();
var dataToPost = JSON.stringify(model);
var data = x2js.json2xml_str(dataToPost);

$.ajax({
  url: '/Home/PostUserData1',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    xml: data
  },
  contentType: 'text/xml; encoding=utf-8',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function(result) {
    if (result === "Error") {

    } else if (result === "OK") {}
  },
  error: function(request) {}
});
```

My controller is as follows

```csharp
public JsonResult PostUserData1(string xml)
{

}
```

I am seeing XML is `null` when I am debugging.

Comment: Depending on how your ModelBinder is configured, try just `data: xml` in your AJAX request.

Comment: Tried that also no luck

Comment: Are you attempting to send binary File information in XML? If so, that's not going to work at all.

Comment: Oh is it but I am trying to solve an issue as per here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69431199/encoding-arraybuffer-to-base64-and-passing-it-to-mvc-controller-doesnt-work-for I am trying different options

Comment: You can pass base64 as JSON.  Don't know why you're bothering with XML.

Comment: Are you sure the file received was valid? You either need to encode the file data (eg. as a  Base64 string) or use FormData to encode it correctly

Comment: Yes I am able to pass, but as said in the other post when the file size is 10MB I am in to that issue

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes the file was a valid one here is the sample code of JSON version https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkGMSNxvuE7Wgj9_c6cG8iHTgjjG?e=FVb9YM

Comment: You're most likely hitting the MaxRequestLength restriction on your server - especially if you are actually base64 encoding the file as it will make the request ~30% larger. You most likely need to reconfigure your server to accept large files, and/or consider using FormData to encode the request data to reduce bandwidth cost and improve performance.

Comment: But as said when I tested with 10MB files it didn't worked so I am trying with XML one

Comment: @RoryMcCrossanI set it to 3GB as per one of the suggestion in my config as follows 3145728 but still it didn't worked

Comment: Have you considered BSON?

Comment: Nope what it is?